# How to replace incomplete rows from complete rows per group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

Trying to clean a dataset and I suspect I'm dealing with incomplete rows with the right information elsewhere in the data frame. For example, something like

| ride_id | start_station_name | start_lat | start_lng |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12398213 | Clark & Vermont | 85.56 | 40.34 |
| 12398129 | NaN | 85.56 | 40.34 |

This would just be one of many such cases (for multiple stations). Curious how you guys might go about searching through the data frame replacing the "NaN" with "Clark and Vermont" using `start_lat` and `start_lng`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Group by](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the latitude and longitude, then [forward-fill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html) and [backward-fill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.bfill.html) the station name.

Using a slightly bigger dataframe for demonstration:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ride_id': range(100, 105), 'station_name': ['Clark & Vermont', np.nan, np.nan, 'Foo & Bar', np.nan], 'start_lat': [85.56]*2 + [15.59]*3, 'start_lng': [40.34]*2 + [20.30]*3})

#    ride_id     station_name  start_lat  start_lng
# 0      100  Clark & Vermont      85.56      40.34
# 1      101              NaN      85.56      40.34
# 2      102              NaN      15.59      20.30
# 3      103        Foo & Bar      15.59      20.30
# 4      104              NaN      15.59      20.30
```

Output:

```
df['station_name'] = df.groupby(['start_lat', 'start_lng'])['station_name'].ffill().bfill()

#    ride_id     station_name  start_lat  start_lng
# 0      100  Clark & Vermont      85.56      40.34
# 1      101  Clark & Vermont      85.56      40.34
# 2      102        Foo & Bar      15.59      20.30
# 3      103        Foo & Bar      15.59      20.30
# 4      104        Foo & Bar      15.59      20.30
```

Comment: Note that this assumes all groups have at least 1 valid station name. If it's possible that a certain group might have 0 valid station names (all NaN), then do the `ffill`/`bfill` inside `groupby.apply` instead

Comment: i.e., `df.groupby(['start_lat', 'start_lng'])['station_name'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())`